# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [MyXYZ.class]

Tags: java, spring, maven, solr

I am implementing a RESTful web application with Jersey+Spring+Mongo+Solr.

After adding the solr dependency, the application is not working on production environment. However, It's works when I run it with in Eclipse (by using Run As >> Run on server).

Below is the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE HTTP CLIENT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- APACHE-COMMONS_COLLECTIONS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- APACHE IO UTILITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- BASE64 ENCODING DECODING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- DOZER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JAVA MAIL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JODA_TIME -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data Solr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is the full stack trace

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/isank/hacks/servers/apache-tomcat-prod/webapps/dpdoctor/WEB-INF/classes/com/dpdocter/collections/PatientClinicalNotesCollection.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:96)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 36 more

Jul 24, 2015 1:41:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 24, 2015 1:41:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/dpdoctor] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 24, 2015 1:41:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 24, 2015 1:41:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5685)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know there are questions similar to this one with accepted solutions, but that's not working for me. For eg. I have tried changing the versions in pom and etc.

Here's also the maven dependency resolution tree (mvn dependency:tree)

```
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:pom:3.2.12.RELEASE:import
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile (version selected from constraint [2.5.2,3))
[INFO] |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-solr:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:4.10.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
```

I'm sorry if I missed something from this tree, I am not an expert in that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following in pom.xml?

```
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Reference: http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/29/spring-asm-dependency-issue-incompatibleclasschangeerror-classmetadatareadingvisitor-classvisitor

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. Could you please explain me this thing. I'm seriously not getting it. And why all of a sudden? I mean it was running smooth without this exclusion thing before and now this. Why?

Comment: Please accept this answer if it worked for you. Thanks in advance. Please check my post (http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/29/spring-asm-dependency-issue-incompatibleclasschangeerror-classmetadatareadingvisitor-classvisitor) for details.